# I would like to test the stocktwits API on localhost. Is this possible?

Tags: javascript, oauth, oauth-2.0, stocktwits

Right now I am integrating a meteor.js app with the stocktwits API. Since I have not decided on a domain name yet and may be far off from this process, is there anyway test the stocktwits api locally (localhost, port 3000) ? Ideally I would like localhost:3000 for my "Website URL" and "Site Domain." However when I try to set these under the ST API create an app dashboard, I am getting errors about invalid website url and site domain. Any workarounds here ??

Also I would like my redirect_uri to be http://localhost:3000/_oauth/stocktwits

When I try to authorize the user the stocktwits popup window does appear - however I get the following error: **Error: invalid_request redirect_uri must be absolute with http or https scheme** I am assuming that is because my redirect_uri is not a live domain name.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this myself, but was unable to do it. The call has to travel from the server to StockTwits, then back but http://localhost is not available outside of your network.

I setup a testing domain on a live web server to test and it worked just fine. Good luck!